# Properties of zero diagonal block matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let A be a $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix, where every $B_{ij}$ is a $n \times n$ submatrix.

in the case of n=3:

\begin{equation}
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & B_{12} & B_{13}
\\ 
B_{21} & 0 & B_{23}
\\
B_{31} & B_{32} & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Are there any properties that classify this class of matrices? (if it helps consider A symmetric)

Can anything be inferefed about it's eigenvalues or signature, or any other algebraic invariants? (Or anything that you observe)

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric and invertible, it can be deduced that the positive and negative indices of inertia are non-zero. That is, $A$ is neither positive nor negative definite.

Comment: In general, if $A$ is symmetric, the only information that we can deduce about the eigenvalues is that their sum is zero.

Comment: Thanks but sadly that's also true for symmetric matrices whose block diagonals are not necessarily zero.